# Making a time series from MEI ENSO index data (url attached): R

Tags: r, time-series, timeserieschart

http://www.esrl.noaa.gov/psd/enso/mei/table.html

I am trying to make a time series from the data in the url above using R 
I have already moved it into excel and created a CSV file, using the following:

```
mei = read.table("MEI.csv", sep=",", header=TRUE)
```

producing a table in R. I want to turn this into a time series, any idea?